# Plotting a pandas panel colum across third dimension

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have 3 separate dataframes of the same shape with following data.

```
# for 2015
Grave Crimes    Cases Recorded  Mistake of Law fact
Abduction       725             3
Kidnapping      246             6
Arson           466             1
Mischief        436             1
House Breaking  12707           21
Grievous Hurt   1299            3

# for 2016
Grave Crimes    Cases Recorded  Mistake of Law fact
Abduction       738             4
Kidnapping      297             9
Arson           486             4
Mischief        394             1
House Breaking  10287           14
Grievous Hurt   1205            0

# for 2017
Grave Crimes    Cases Recorded  Mistake of Law fact
Abduction       647             2
Kidnapping      251             10
Arson           418             3
Mischief        424             0
House Breaking  8913            12
Grievous Hurt   1075            1
```

I want to plot each column (say 'Cases Recorded' for example) against the 'Grave Crimes' type group by the year. My current panel is as follows. I did not set any indexes when creating the panel. Also each dataframe doesn't have any column indicating the year as shown above.

`pnl = pd.Panel({2015: df15, 2016: df16, 2017: df17})`

My expected output is shown below. Can someone help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panels have been deprecated in Pandas as of 0.20.1+

We can use pd.concat with keys to combine those dataframes into a single dataframe, then use reshaping and pandas plot.

```
l = ['df2015','df2016','df2017']
df_out = pd.concat([eval(i) for i in l], keys=l)\
           .set_index('Grave Crimes',append=True)['Cases Recorded'].unstack(0)\
           .rename(columns=lambda x: x[2:]).reset_index(0, drop=True)

df_out.plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]